# my table is not fitting in IEEE conference format . How to make it fit in

Tags: tables, ieeeconf

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{An environmental details for the experiment.}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
\hline
    Room & Living room   \\ \hline
    Sensors and camera position & Ceiling   \\ \hline
    Sensor and camera Distance from floor  & 2.6 m \\ \hline    
    Room Temperature & $24^{\circ}$C   \\ \hline
    Subject & Human   \\ \hline
    Position of subject to sensor & All positions possible    \\ \hline
    Activities & Walking, Sitting, Standing, Falling, Lying, Action change    \\ \hline
    Subject & 5 person  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{exp}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A quick hint: if you highlight a code chunk and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the editing window, the site software will pretty-print it for you.

Answer (score 3):

- Your need to break cell contents in your table on two lines. For examples by use of the `tabularx` table (defined in the package of the same name).
- For units I would use `siunitx`.
- For better table design see @mico answer.
- I would type your table as follows:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\centering
\caption{An environmental details for the experiment.}
\label{exp}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l | L | }
\hline
    Room & Living room   \\ \hline
    Sensors and camera position & Ceiling   \\ \hline
    Sensor and camera Distance from floor  & \SI{2.6}{m} \\ \hline
    Room Temperature & \SI{24}{\celsius}   \\ \hline
    Subject & Human   \\ \hline
    Position of subject to sensor & All positions possible    \\ \hline
    Activities & Walking, Sitting, Standing, Falling, Lying, Action change    \\ \hline
    Subject & 5 person  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you its worked finally

Answer (score 3):

The table doesn't fit within the width of a column because line breaking isn't enabled.

I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment, set its width to `\columnwidth`, and use `X`-type columns to permit line-breaking inside cells. In the solution shown below, I define a new column type, called `L`, which is based on the `X` column type and performs hanging indentation. I recommend left-aligning rather than centering both columns. I would also like to suggest that you give the table a much more open "look" by omitting all vertical lines and using fewer, but well spaced horizontal lines. Finally, to typeset numbers and their associated units, do employ the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Environmental details for experiment.}
\label{exp}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ @{} LL @{} }
\toprule
  Room & Living room  \\ 
\midrule % optional, feel free to omit
  Sensors and camera position & Ceiling  \\ 
  Sensor and camera distance from floor & \SI{2.6}{\meter} \\   
  Room Temperature & \SI{24}{\celsius}  \\ 
  Subject & Human  \\ 
  Position of subject to sensor & All positions possible  \\ 
  Activities & Walking, sitting, standing, falling, lying, action change  \\ 
  Subject & 5 persons  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked

Comment: still i had pblm when i use the first code. can you help me again

Comment: @MuthukumarK.A. - And what would that problem be? (Sadly, but maybe not surprisingly, my psychic abilities are rubbish.)

Comment: \begin{table}
\caption{Environmental details for experiment.}
\label{exp}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ @{} LL @{} }
\toprule
  Room & Living room  \\ 
  Sensors and camera position & Ceiling  \\ 
  Sensor and camera distance from floor & \SI{2.6}{\meter} \\   
  Room Temperature & \SI{24}{\celsius}  \\ 
  Subject & Human  \\ 
  Position of subject to sensor & All positions possible  \\ 
  Activities & Walking, sitting, standing, falling, lying, action change  \\ 
  Subject & 5 persons  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} it says error

Comment: @MuthukumarK.A. -- And *what* is the error? My psychic abilities are still rubbish... What I do know for sure is that the code I posted above does *not* throw any errors. If you're encountering errors in your document, you really need to inform me *which error* message(s) you're getting. Incidentally, did you remember to copy the preamble instructions `\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}`, `\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}`, and `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}` into your document?

Comment: it worked i updated the packages its worked . Thanks a lot for help